# How to conclude a website is not receptive to upload by inspecting the sites elements?

Tags: image, google-chrome, upload, element

I’m concerned that I accidently pasted a wrong photo to a website.
I tried replicating the process:
If I copy a picture from Gimp, open the website and Ctrl. V a random place on the website.
I have monitored network activity for Chrome using Windows Resource Monitor, and it shows no upload activity when I Ctrl V.

1.
How can I conclude, that the picture / data has not been uploaded to the website when I Ctrl. V a place on the website?

2.
I have tried inspecting elements on the given website using Google Chrome, but I don’t know what to look for, to make sure the website is not receptive to upload / pasting pictures?

Thanks in advance for replying

Best regards

Comment: HTML can't upload simply by pasting (which is why just inspecting the elements can't help you). You would need JavaScript for it. Since a tool to find upload capability a priori in JavaScript code is not possible, the only way would be to either read the code, or execute it. If you want to be sure a website can't upload just by pasting, disable JavaScript on it (which might likely kill the usefulness of the website itself).

Comment: Dear Amadan, thank you for your comment. So how would you find out, if a website has elements that is receptive to file upload?@Amadan

Comment: "the only way would be to either read the code, or execute it".